# Как передать ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>> в другую активити?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

У меня есть модель:

```
public class Event {

    private int voltage;
    private Date date;

    public Event(Date date, int voltage){
        this.date = date;
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public int getVoltage() {
        return voltage;
    }

    public void setVoltage(int voltage) {
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }  
}
```

Из этой модели я создаю списки `ArrayList<Event> eventList`, все эти списки я помещаю в один большой список - `ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>> full_event_list`;

Подскажите как правильно передать данную конструкцию в другую активити?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой и быстрый по реализации, но медленный в рантайме способ - указать, что класс `implements Serializable`, после чего передавать его экземпляры через `Intent#putSerializable(String key, Serializable value)`

Долгий и сложный по реализации, но быстрый в рантайме - указать, что класс `implements Parcelable`. При этом надо вручную каждое поле сохранять/считывать. Передавать его экземпляры через `Intent#putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)`.

Для последнего способа есть либа:https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Comment: Позвольте уточнить по поводу либы, для того чтобы отправить мой двойной список, мне нужно ставить аннотацию не для моей модели (которая в вопросе), а создавать новую модель, где создается двойной список, правильно?

Comment: @Denis422, нет, достаточно аннотации для модели, а потом передавать её методом `putParcelableArrayList`. Сколько уровней вложенности ArrayList-ов будет - не важно.

Answer (score 2):

Реализую такую (и не только) задачу через "Лабы" ([Учебник](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxhbmRsZXNzb25zfGd4OjNjMjBlNzMwZDUwNmM2YWM)).

Примерно так:

```
public class SymbolLab {
    private static SymbolLab symbolLab;      
    private ArrayList<Symbol> symbols;   

public static SymbolLab get(Context ctx) {
    if (symbolLab == null)
        symbolLab = new SymbolLab(ctx);
    return symbolLab;
}

private SymbolLab(Context ctx) {
       создание массива данных
}

public ArrayList<Symbol> getSymbols(){
    return symbols;
}
```

доступ из любой точки приложения: `SymbolLab.get(this/getActivity()).getSymbols()`

Answer (score 2):

Кроме православных методов описанных @ЮрийСПб предложу 2 не очень православных способа:

1. Засунуть весь ваш массив в JSon строку (легко делается через Google Gson - код буквально в 1 строчку) и отправить как `putStringExtra()`, на той стороне вытащить и обратно же из Json в ваш объект (опять же не без помощи Google Gson)
2. Весь ваш массив хранить в классе `Application` и извлекать оттуда по мере надобности.

P.S. Второй способ совсем не православный :)

Comment: Кстати да, я совсем забыл, что `json` можно гонять не только по сети, но и по самому приложению