# Передача экземпляра класса во Fragment

Tags: java, android

Необходимо передать экземпляр класса из одного фрагмента в другой.
Знаю что можно передавать переменные через Bundle

```
fragment = new SmartphoneMainTab();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("id",product.getId());
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Но как передать экземпляр класса?

Comment: зачем вам там экземпляр класса?) что бы вы не задумали, полагаю, есть способ проще

Comment: Просто хотел не тратить время на загрузку товара в другом фрагменте, если в предыдущем мы его загрузили уже.

Comment: понял, что вы имеете ввиду) я бы использовал для этой задачи "лабы". Посмотрите, я здесь отвечал, как их делать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylistarraylistcustomobject-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8/664499#664499 . Вкратце: у вас все лежит в одном месте (в лабе) и доступ к ней есть отовсюду. Достаточно знать id

Answer (score 0):

Может быть попробовать через putParcelable?:

```
fragment = new SmartphoneMainTab();
NewObject newObject = new NewObject();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("Object", newObject);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Затем в onCreate фрагмента:

```
NewObject newObject = (NewObject) bundle.getParcelable("Object");
```

Но ваш класс должен реализовывать интерфейс [Parcelable](https://drone-ah.com/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Отправка

```
fragment = new SmartphoneMainTab();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("model", product);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Получение

```
Product product = (Product) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("model");
```