# Данные для Fragments из SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragment, activity

Есть БД допустим с клиентами в нем ФИО, номер, адрес, дата рождения, ну и т.д. Так вот эти данные нужны будут в TabbedActivity для всех фрагментов входящих в него около 5 шт. Как правильно реализовать получение данных из БД. Думаю не разумно обращаться к БД в каждом фрагменте.

Comment: создайте синглтон класс, куда вы на старте (или когда надо) подгрузите все данные и будете получить их по мере необходимости. Посмотрите, как примерно это должно выглядеть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylistarraylistcustomobject-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8/664499#664499

Comment: Да как раз такие эту книгу читаю, и занал про синглтон но что-то не додумался. Спасибо, думаю что что мое нужно.